# How \printbibliography works?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I have to insert a bibliography into my document and to do this I use the following code, written referring to [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_biblatex) guide. Unfortunately, it does not work: more precisely into my document appear all things correctly except for the bibliography. I point out I installed on my computer TeXlive distribution, I use XelaTeX to compile and I use TeXstudio to do this but actually I tried also to use TeXwork, TeXmaker and overleaf without any successful so that I thought to put here a specific question where I ask how \printbibliography works: more precisely I have to set in a specific way my compiler? I have to upload a more specifica package than biblatex package? I have to insert a more specific command than \printbibliography? So could someone help me, please?

To follow my code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography_contents.bib}
    @book{1,
        title={Lógica Matemática},
        author={José Ferrater Mora, Hughes Leblanc},
        year={1962},
        publisher={Fondo de Cultura Económica}
    }
    @book{2,
        title={Set theory for the mathematician},
        author={Jean E. Rubin},
        publisher={Holden-Day},
        year={1967}
    }
    @article{3
        title={An introduction to algebraic structures},
        author={Azriel Rosenfeld},
        publisher={Holden-Day},
        year={1968}
    }
    @book{4,
        title={Set theory and logic},
        author={Robert R. Stoll},
        year={1979},
        publisher={Dover Publication}
    }
    @book{5,
        title={Teoría de conjuntos},
        author={Fernando Hernández Hernández},
        year={1998},
        publisher={Sociedad Matemática Mexicana}
    }
    @book{6,
        title={Introduction to set theory, revised and expanded},
        author={Karel Hrbacek, Jech Thomas},
        year={1999},
        publisher={Marcel Dekker}
    }
    @book{7,
        title={Teoría de los Conjuntos, Curso intermedio},
        author={José Alfredo, Amor Montaño, Gabriela Campero Arena, Favio Ezequiel Miranda Perea},
        publisher={Las prensas de Ciencias},
        year={2010}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{bibliography_contents.bib}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{Chapter}
    This is a chapter.
    
    \printbibliography[title={Indice bibliografico}, heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Type `@article{3,` instead of `@article{3` (the comma is missing).

Comment: @hair-splitter Thanks for the observation: unfortunately, I did it now but nothing changed.

Comment: you need to run xelatex than bibtex (as you have changed from the default biber) then xelatex twice more. Note that while it's possible to use a key such as "5" it's a really bad idea: the key should be a symbolic identifier `Tdc1988` or some such, latex/bibtex will choose a number based on the bibliography style and it may be any number or you may use an unnumbered style so using "5" as a key would just be confusing

Comment: `\printbibliography` only prints entries which have been cited, and you cite none. If you want to include all entries in your .bib file, use `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: Do not separate the authors' names with commas, but with `and`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I indicated the errors in the source.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes} % this is used by biblatex

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography_contents.bib}
    @book{1,
        title={Lógica Matemática},
        author={José Ferrater Mora and Hughes Leblanc}, % 'and' instead of comma
        year={1962},
        publisher={Fondo de Cultura Económica}
    }
    @book{2,
        title={Set theory for the mathematician},
        author={Jean E. Rubin},
        publisher={Holden-Day},
        year={1967}
    }
    @article{3, % the comma was missing
        title={An introduction to algebraic structures},
        author={Azriel Rosenfeld},
        publisher={Holden-Day},
        year={1968}
    }
    @book{4,
        title={Set theory and logic},
        author={Robert R. Stoll},
        year={1979},
        publisher={Dover Publication}
    }
    @book{5,
        title={Teoría de conjuntos},
        author={Fernando Hernández Hernández},
        year={1998},
        publisher={Sociedad Matemática Mexicana}
    }
    @book{6,
        title={Introduction to set theory, revised and expanded},
        author={Karel Hrbacek and Jech Thomas},  % 'and' instead of comma
        year={1999},
        publisher={Marcel Dekker}
    }
    @book{7,
        title={Teoría de los Conjuntos, Curso intermedio},
        author={José Alfredo and Amor Montaño and Gabriela Campero Arena and Favio Ezequiel Miranda Perea},  % 'and' instead of comma
        publisher={Las prensas de Ciencias},
        year={2010}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{bibliography_contents.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
This is a chapter.

\nocite{*} % This will display all elements even without \cite
\printbibliography[title={Indice bibliografico}, heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer: now the code works correctly. Only two questions: it is impossibile to print the comma into the author entry? moreover I would like to print text ordered by date of publication: is it possibile?

Comment: I did it but strangerly the compiler do not print the comma: I think I will put a specific question about. I upvoted and approved your answer: thanks very much for the assistance! :-)

Comment: For order by year, type this: `\usepackage[sorting=ynt]{biblatex}`

Comment: To separate names with commas, type this: `\def\finalnamedelim{\addcomma\addspace}`

Comment: The solution for chronological order works perfectly; however the same is not for that of comma.

Comment: I found a possibile solution for commas at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149179/296807) answer: into my code it works perfectly.